# Spark dataframe replace values of specific columns in a row with Nulls

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, null, apache-spark-sql

I am facing a problem when trying to replace the values of specific columns of a Spark dataframe with nulls.
I have a dataframe with more than fifty columns of which two are key columns. I want to create a new dataframe with same schema and the new dataframe should have values from the key columns and null values in non-key columns. 
I tried the following ways but facing issues:

```
//old_df is the existing Dataframe 
val key_cols = List("id", "key_number")
val non_key_cols = old_df.columns.toList.filterNot(key_cols.contains(_))

val key_col_df = old_df.select(key_cols.head, key_cols.tail:_*)
val non_key_cols_df = old_df.select(non_key_cols.head, non_key_cols.tail:_*)
val list_cols = List.fill(non_key_cols_df.columns.size)("NULL")
val rdd_list_cols = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(list_cols)).map(l => Row(l:_*))
val list_df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd_list_cols, non_key_cols_df.schema)

val new_df = key_col_df.crossJoin(list_df)
```

This approach was good when I only have string type columns in the `old_df`. But I have some columns of double type and int type which is throwing error because the rdd is a list of null strings.

To avoid this I tried the `list_df` as an empty dataframe with schema as the `non_key_cols_df` but the result of `crossJoin` is an empty dataframe which I believe is because one dataframe is empty.

My requirement is to have the `non_key_cols` as a single row dataframe with Nulls so that I can do `crossJoin` with `key_col_df` and form the required `new_df`.

Also any other easier way to update all columns except key columns of a dataframe to nulls will resolve my issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crossJoin` is an expensive operation so you want to avoid it if possible.
An easier solution would be to iterate over all non-key columns and insert null with `lit(null)`. Using `foldLeft` this can be done as follows:

```
val keyCols = List("id", "key_number")
val nonKeyCols = df.columns.filterNot(keyCols.contains(_))

val df2 = nonKeyCols.foldLeft(df)((df, c) => df.withColumn(c, lit(null)))
```

Input example:

```
+---+----------+---+----+
| id|key_number|  c|   d|
+---+----------+---+----+
|  1|         2|  3| 4.0|
|  5|         6|  7| 8.0|
|  9|        10| 11|12.0|
+---+----------+---+----+
```

will give:

```
+---+----------+----+----+
| id|key_number|   c|   d|
+---+----------+----+----+
|  1|         2|null|null|
|  5|         6|null|null|
|  9|        10|null|null|
+---+----------+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Shaido answer has small drawback - column type will be lost.
Can be fixed with schema usage, like this:

```
val nonKeyCols = df.schema.fields.filterNot(f => keyCols.contains(f.name))
val df2 = nonKeyCols.foldLeft(df)((df, c) => df.withColumn(c.name, lit(null).cast(c.dataType)))
```

Comment: Thank you for correction, though my requirement was fulfilled even with NullType. I am using the obtained DF to union with another DF and the resultant DF schema  does not have NullType

Comment: If other dataframe will be empty, or dataframe union order will be changed during refactoring, issues can occurs. Guess, with proper schema is more reliable solution.

Comment: Yes, when I ran the code in spark shell, I faced the issue when first Dataframe was empty, I tried to cast using c.cast(dataType) but it threw an error saying cannot cast, String cannot have a dataType.